# Implementing interfaces within interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I'm writing some code for importing files which will import either delimited or fixed width files based on a template that describes the file layout.

I've created an interface IFileTemplate:

```
public interface IFileTemplate
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   bool IgnoreEmptyLines { get; set; }
}
```

which is used by a `DelimitedFileTemplate` class  and a `FixedWidthFileTemplate` class.

I also have an interface for specifying each of the columns that make up a template:

```
public interface IFileTemplateColumn
{
   int ID { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   bool Ignore { get; set; }
}
```

This interface is then used by a `DelimitedTemplateColumn` class and a `FixedWidthTemplateColumn` class.

As both the DelimitedFileTemplate and FixedWidthFileTemplate classes will have a list of columns I've made the list a member of the IFileTemplate column:

```
List<IFileTemplateColumn> Fields { get; set; }
```

My problem is when I've come to implement the list in the DelimitedFileTemplate and FixedWidthFileTemplate classes, for example:

```
public class FixedWidthFileTemplate : IFileTemplate
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<FixedWidthFileTemplateColumn> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

If I try and implement `List<IFileTemplateColumn>` with `List<DelimitedFileTemplateColumn>` or `List<FixedWidthFileTemplateColumn>` then the compiler complains that they don't match `List<IFileTemplateColumn>`.

I can understand this but it seems wrong not to have the column list in the ITemplateInterface. The only get around I can think of is to have the Delimited and FixedWidth classes use `List<IFileTemplateColumn>` and have the property getter cast the list to the delimited or fixed width column list but there seems a bit of code smell to that. Can anyone suggest a better way for doing this?

Comment: It would be better if you add code for classes where you have implemented interfaces. It will be more readable.

Comment: @FaisalHafeez Good suggestion, now updated.

Comment: I would step back and ask why you have interfaces at all. Will there be three classes that implement each interface but have no common base class other than object?

Comment: @EricLippert I initially picked interfaces as the code was going to be used by a couple of other projects and thought interfaces would be more appropriate if used across boundaries. As the interfaces aren't going to be used outside of this code (calling code will only used the classes implementing the interface) I may reconsider this. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Well, strings are used across many projects but there is no `IString` interface. Integers are used across many projects but there is no `IInteger` interface. Use interfaces when you have many unrelated classes that provide similar functionality; `IEnumerable` for example. There are many ways to implement a sequence that have nothing to do with each other. A good guidelines is: if you're not going to have three or more implementations, don't make an interface.

Comment: @EricLippert that directly contradicts http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle - not to mention that I never could figure out the reason for it even outside of "violates DIP". What is wrong with using an interface even when there's a single implementation?

Comment: @MarcelPopescu: If you accept that dependency inversion is a good idea then my rule of thumb is a bad idea. The logical conclusion that you should reach is that I don't think that dependency inversion is a particularly good idea.

Comment: @MarcelPopescu: To address your specific question, see my earlier comment. Why is there no `IString` or `IInteger`?  Shouldn't we be passing an `IString` to every method that takes a string and an `IInteger` to every method that takes an integer, in case we want to *injectionify* the method?

Comment: String is a primitive - its main use case is getting and setting a value. CloudUploader, TokenManager, FileSystemMonitor are services; in  the system I'm currently developing, the last two have a single implementation each. Every time I skip the "first, create an interface" step I regret it later.

Comment: @MarcelPopescu: Another way to look at it is: if your services are so complicated, so stateful, and so dependent on other services that you need to be able to inject fake versions of the dependencies in order to successfully test the services, then maybe it's a good idea to redesign those services to *act more like values*.

Comment: @EricLippert ok, I could use an article about this because I have no idea how to do it (and it sounds intriguing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable and not smelly solution to this design problem are generics:

```
interface IFileTemplate<T> where T : IFileTemplateColumn
{
    List<T> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

`DelimitedFileTemplate` implements `IFileTemplate<DelimitedFileTemplateColumn>` and so on.

Perhaps all the differences between the file templates could be sensibly defined by `IFileTemplateColumn` only and you could simplify things with `FileTemplate<IFileTemplateColumn>` insted of one FileTemplate class per one FileTemplateColumn class relation.

**Update**

As for the factory method: `IFileTemplate<IFileTemplateColumn> Create`: if the consumers of this method are supposed to be able to access the list of columns, the method signature will have to contain the concrete ColumnTemplate. For example:

```
DelimitedFileTemplate Create
```

**or**

```
interface IFactory<T> where T : IFileTemplateColumn
{
    IFileTemplate<T> Create();
}

class DelimitedFactory : IFactory<DelimitedFileTemplateColumn>
{
    IFileTemplate<DelimitedFileTemplateColumn> Create() 
    {
        return new DelimitedFileTemplate();
    }
}
```

If the consumers of the method won't be interested in the list, introduce a more general interface (much like `IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable`):

```
interface IFileTemplate { ... }
interface IFileTemplate<T> : IFileTemplate where T : IFileTemplateColumn
{
    List<IFileTemplateColumn> Columns { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `IFileTemplate Create()` method could return any of the concrete FileTemplate regardless of the column.

I've worked with this kind of generics usage and they might tend to propagate (in this example Column hierarchy will be duplicated in FileTemplate hierarchy and might be duplicated in the factory hierarchy). Sometimes this reveals some flaws in the design. If you were able to sensibly cut the IFileTemplate hierarchy to one base parametrized FileTemplate class, this was certainly the way to go. This is how I often use this: define the smallest parts, if the hierarchy tends to duplicate, some parts of the algorithms can be perhaps moved to the 'smallest-parts-classes'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found it easier to go with your second suggestion when implementing this solution with MVVM. Returning a list of all the templates would have been too difficult to manage if the list were to contain different types of template.

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush glad you were able to work this out on your own. i finally had some time to get back to this - see update, i had similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that's given me a few more things to look into. Cheers.